# Xampp SSL Setup - Certificates Imported, by "connection is not secure"

Tags: php, apache, ssl, openssl, xampp

I've been trying to make my local Xampp-based website properly use SSL for our local intranet system.

Windows Edition: Windows Server 2016 Standard
XAMPP Version 7.4.1
PHP Version 7.4.1

HTTP Port: 8080
SSL Port: 4443

I followed Apache Tutorial, which uses Xampp's version of Openssl to create the necessary certificates for SSL.

https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=77006&sid=e0291bc38dd9b562cd74e5f72153c1f7#

These steps get the un-encrypted version up and running:

- Hosts File: Add "127.0.0.1    www.site.local"
- httpd.conf: Add "Listen: 8080"
- httpd.conf: Add "ServerName www.site.local:8080"

Now, I create the ssl root ca and certificate request:

- Create Private Key "openssl genrsa -out myrootca.key 4096"
- Create Root Certificate "openssl req -new -x509 -days 1826 -key myrootca.key -out myrootca.crt
- Create Domain Certificate "openssl genrsa -out www.site.local.key 2048"
- Create Signing Request "openssl req -new -sha256 -key www.site.local.key -out www.site.local.csr -sha256"
- Create Certificate, signed with my Root CA "openssl x509 -req -days 360 -in www.site.local.csr -CA myrootca.crt -CAkey myrootca.key -CAcreateserial -out www.site.local.crt -sha256"
- I placed these certificate and key in their respective paths:

  - C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.crt/www.site.local.crt
  - C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.key/www.site.local.key

(Setup file "httpd-ssl" to incorporate these certificates)

```
Listen 4443
<VirtualHost default:4443>

#   General setup for the virtual host
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/site_intranet/"
    ServerName www.site.local:4443
    ServerAlias www.site.local
    ErrorLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
    TransferLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.crt/www.site.local.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.key/www.site.local.key"
```

(Import ROOT CA to Browser and Windows)
- Import to Windows as a trusted CA: Check
- Firefox Browser: Check

Problem: all attempts to access www.site.local (by either port) result in the "not secure" warning from Firefox.

I've tried to check Apache errors for some guidance. It's running fine.

The only Firefox error I get is "This website does not supply ownership information."

I know you can no longer just put in a basic certificate, but I'd hoped that first building a Root CA and then designing the certificate from that would provide the chain of trust required to enable SSL. Am I missing something simple here?

I have been asked for something that secure's locally, without any third-party sources for certificates. Got to make something work locally.

Answer (score 1):

I think here is a blog you can follow to solve your issue by ACME Root CA:

https://medium.com/@tbusser/creating-a-browser-trusted-self-signed-ssl-certificate-2709ce43fd15

Here're recap from the blog:

Command Recap

The following commands are needed to create a root certificate:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024  -out rootCA.pem
```

The following commands are needed to create an SSL certificate issued by the self created root certificate:

```
openssl req -new -nodes -out server.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 500 -sha256 -extfile v3.ext
```

The referenced v3.ext file should look something like this:

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = acme-site.dev
DNS.2 = acme-static.dev
```

Thanks for Thijs Busser.